# How to detect IIS events in windows event logs and detemine its application pool according to this code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, event-handling, application-pool

I try to make a listener on windows event logs, but I need to recognize IIS events in it and determine its application pool.
could I do that according to this code ??? by process id for example or any thing else.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using Microsoft.Web;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

namespace EventLogEnt
{
    class Program
    {
        static AutoResetEvent signal;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {  
            // create new log
            signal = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            EventLog myNewLog = new EventLog("Application", "TIS3", "Outlook");

            myNewLog.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(MyOnEntryWritten);
            myNewLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            myNewLog.WriteEntry("Test message", EventLogEntryType.Information);
            signal.WaitOne();
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
        public static void MyOnEntryWritten(object source, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Entry.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("the entry type: " + e.Entry.EntryType);
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------");
            signal.Set();
        }

    }
}
```